# Как правильно организовать использование внешнего API в Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, архитектура

Приложение на Laravel.

Стоит задача внедрить несколько внешних API (VK, Bitrix24, Unisender и некоторые другие). Было бы неплохо хранить их в условной папке Api (Api\Bitrix, Api\VK, Api\Unisender).

Можно всю логику работы с API описывать в сервисах, а потом регистрировать их в сервис-контейнере или это плохая практика?

Есть ли какие-то общепринятые практики в этом направлении?

Answer (score 0):

Всё же более опытные коллеги подсказали, что один из самых распространенных (и любимых разработчиками) методов - вынесение логики работы с API в сервисы, это очень изолированный и легко переносимый код.

Насчет структуры папок. Получилось вот так:

```
App\Services\Bitrix24\...
App\Services\VK\...
```

Также в этих папках можно создавать подкаталоги, если API разрастается. Получилось очень удобно. Надеюсь, кому-то поможет :)